# h2o model performance extraction

Tags: python, h2o

After trained a random forest classifier using `h2o H2ORandomForestEstimator` , how could I extract the model performance report for different metrics?

```
ModelMetricsBinomial: drf
** Reported on train data. **

MSE: 0.3585693234630144
RMSE: 0.5988065826817658
LogLoss: 1.042047808195111
Mean Per-Class Error: 0.3219540722169749
AUC: 0.7464490458314232
AUCPR: 0.751360355831092
Gini: 0.4928980916628465

Confusion Matrix (Act/Pred) for max f1 @ threshold = 0.06774124943480285: 
False   True    Error   Rate

...
```

For example I trained many different models using this process and want to compare the final results so it's better to save model_performance for later use.
I expect to save as:

```
 {model1 : model_performance_1,
  model2 : model_performance_2, ........}
```

Moreover How could I extract the model performance values? For example how to
extract the values of confusion_matrix, like to extract the values of confusion matrix itself?
`perf.confusion_matrix()` return h2o object, but how to extract it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the model metrics by calling their respective methods. E.g. `model1.mse()`, `model1.auc()`, `model1.gini()`.

For your second question, it's not clear what you are trying to extract. You can make it into a list `perf.confusion_matrix().to_list()`